# Jersey 2 with Jackson1 Feature and Joda DateTime unproper json format

Tags: jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I use Jersey 2 with Jackson Feature and JodaTime DateTime. So it works fine for Dates that I dont need HH:mm:ss, but now I do and the time I receive on the server is always wrong.

After debugging through LoggingFilter I found out the dates were being written like this:

```
{"id":1,"priority":"NORMAL","start":1456747200000,"end":1456527600000,"conclusion":null}
```

And so, after searching I bit I saw a solution saying to enable "WRITE_DATE_AS_TIMESTAMPS". This is how I've done it:

```
@Provider
public class JerseyObjectMapperProvider implements
        ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public JerseyObjectMapperProvider() {
        defaultObjectMapper = createDefaultMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return defaultObjectMapper;
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
        final ObjectMapper result = new ObjectMapper();
        result.configure(Feature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);

        return result;
    }

}
```

And registered:

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig()
                .register(new JerseyObjectMapperProvider())
                .register(new Jackson1Feature())
                .register(new MultiPartFeature()));
```

But this didnt solve my problem. The JSON output was the same. Now I must ask, how to fix this date issue ?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to _enable "WRITE_DATE_AS_TIMESTAMPS"_? What do you think that means? Don't you think you should **dis**able it? The default is true

Comment: I think I miss read it then. Do you have any idea of how I can make Jackson send the correct date format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the joda module:

```
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

here the maven dependency:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```